# Strictly increasing interpolation / spline

Tags: r, interpolation

I have points in the x-y-plane that are strictly increasing most of the time.  The problem is that there are cases with one or two outliers (Knots where an out-of-the-box spline would be decreasing).  Without deleting any data points, is there a way to interpolate / create a spline that is strictly increasing everywhere?  Also, I would like the interpolation to be $C^1$.  (Which package could do this in R?)

Comment: What is $C^1$? Other than that, it sounds like isotonic regression might be a good fit for you needs.

Comment: **mgcv** can fit general penalised regression models with monotonicity constraints using cubic splines. **mgcv** has function `mono.con` for constraints on a cubic spline, and the models are fitted using the `pcls()` function - the help page of which has an example.

Comment: @user777 $C^1$ denotes the smoothness; maybe it is not internationally used - i studied math in Germany.  (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness)

Comment: @both:  upvotes + thx a bunch for your suggestions; I will look into it now.

Comment: CV user Rob Hyndman has some functions available: http://robjhyndman.com/software/monotonic-splines/

Comment: @dotwin The wiki link makes it appear that it is common usage and I'm just ignorant. Anyhow, I'm pretty sure isotonic regression doesn't satisfy the $C^1$ requirement! Interesting question, though!

Comment: R packages ConSpline, cobs, scar, scam and cgam can all fit shape-constrained splines, including monotonically increasing ones - I would try some of these! The cobs package also allows you to specify the desired degree of the splines; 1 for linear spline (equivalent to L_1-roughness) and 2 for quadratic spline (corresponding to L_infinity ('L_oo') roughness). Is this what you are after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R package `cobs` allows you to fit shape-constrained splines, including monotonically increasing ones; syntax would be something like:

```
require(cobs)
fit = cobs(x,y,
      constraint= "increase", 
       lambda=0, 
       degree=1, # for L1 roughness
       knots=seq(min(x),max(x),length.out=10), # desired nr of knots 
       tau=0.5) # to predict median
preds = predict(fit,interval="none",z=xvals)[,2]
```

And R packages ConSpline, scar, scam and cgam offer also alternative options to fit shape-constrained splines, including monotonically increasing ones....

Comment: Example with R code here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206073/looking-for-function-to-fit-sigmoid-like-curve/316446#316446